# Unknown Space Character when Stripping Spaces in VBA

Tags: vba, ascii

I was writing a simple replace script to remove all spaces from a EXCEL Spreadsheet using the built in VBA editor. The code looked to be running fine on data that had been copied and pasted into a blank spreadsheet. However I noticed that some spaces remained. On copying one of these into Word and showing formatting characters and symbols I was given the characters that are seen on the top row of my image. The second row is a copy of the top row with those characters removed and a normal space entered to show the difference. Has anyone come across this character and if so what is it?

[image]

Thanks

Harry

Answer (score 1):

The small circle may be  a [non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), ascii code is 160.
(In Word, you can insert it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>).
In VBA, you can try `s = Replace(s, Chr(160), " ")`.

Answer (score 0):

The are many *unicode* space characters, to see exactly what it is

```
uchar = ascw(mid$(the_string, character_position, 1))
```

then to replace it:

```
the_string = replace$(the_string, chrw$(uchar), "")
```